Superset Kaas deployment error - bad interpreter: Permission denied
Facing issue while deploying superset on KAAS(Kubernetes as a service), facing one error with redis chart dependency- /bin/bash: /opt/bitnami/scripts/start-scripts/start-master.sh: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Permission denied
[apache-superset]
dependencies:

name: postgresql
version: 12.1.6
repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
condition: postgresql.enabled
name: redis
version: 17.9.4
repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
condition: redis.enabled

Tried updating the users, tried updating redis chart version.
